# DropDownList AutoPostBack inside update panel loses css designs

Tags: c#, javascript, drop-down-menu, updatepanel, autopostback

I have this page structure

```
<MasterPage>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.main.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/all2.css" media="all" />
 <ContentPage>

  <updatePanel>
    <asp:DropDownList id="ddlCountry" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"  CssClass="width_412" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
  </updatePanel>

 </ContentPage>
</MasterPage>
```

Now I need `AutoPostBack="True"` for binding states for selected country.

The problem is **"am losing DropDownList designs when I put AutoPostBack="True""**

***without AutoPostBack:***

[image]

***with AutoPostBack:***

[image]

I went inside jquery.main.js and found that *designs for select were replaced dynamically*

```
function replaceSelects() {
for(var q = 0; q < selects.length; q++) {
if (!selects[q].replaced && selects[q].offsetWidth && selects[q].className.indexOf("default") == -1){
    selects[q]._number = q;
    //create and build div structure
    var selectArea = document.createElement("div");
    var left = document.createElement("span");
    left.className = "left";
    selectArea.appendChild(left);
    var disabled = document.createElement("span");
    disabled.className = "disabled";
    selectArea.appendChild(disabled);
    selects[q]._disabled = disabled;
    var center = document.createElement("span");
    var button = document.createElement("a");
    var text = document.createTextNode(selectText);
    center.id = "mySelectText"+q;
    var stWidth = selects[q].offsetWidth;
    selectArea.style.width = stWidth + "px";
    if (selects[q].parentNode.className.indexOf("type2") != -1){
        button.href = "javascript:showOptions("+q+",true)";
    }else{button.href = "javascript:showOptions("+q+",false)";}
    button.className = "selectButton";
    selectArea.className = "selectArea";
    selectArea.className += " " + selects[q].className;
    selectArea.id = "sarea"+q;
    center.className = "center";
    center.appendChild(text);
    selectArea.appendChild(center);
    selectArea.appendChild(button);
    //hide the select field
    selects[q].className += " outtaHere";
    //insert select div
    selects[q].parentNode.insertBefore(selectArea, selects[q]);
    //build & place options div
    var optionsDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var optionsListParent = document.createElement("div");
    optionsListParent.className = "select-center";
    var optionsListParent2 = document.createElement("div");
    optionsListParent2.className = "select-center-right";
    var optionsList = document.createElement("ul");
    optionsDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='select-top'><div class='select-top-left'></div><div class='select-top-right'></div></div>";
    optionsListParent.appendChild(optionsListParent2);
    optionsListParent.appendChild(optionsList);
    optionsDiv.appendChild(optionsListParent);
    selects[q]._options = optionsList;
    optionsDiv.style.width = stWidth + "px";
    optionsDiv._parent = selectArea;
    optionsDiv.className = "optionsDivInvisible";
    optionsDiv.id = "optionsDiv"+q;
    populateSelectOptions(selects[q]);
    optionsDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='select-bottom'><div class='select-bottom-left'></div><div class='select-bottom-right'></div></div>";
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(optionsDiv);
    selects[q].replaced = true;
    }
all_selects = true;
  }
  }
```

I think the update panel gets postbacked on load,Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

> I went inside jquery.main.js and found that designs for select were replaced dynamically

I'm afraid UpdatePanel works by *replacing* all of the content inside of it.  That's why your styling is getting destroyed.

If keeping the styling is important to you, you have two options:

- Move to a more native AJAX solution.  Ie, catch the change in JavaScript, then make an AJAX call to some web service or even static method in your page to do what you need to do.
- See if there's a way to get jQuery to re-style you dropdown after every call from the UpdatePanel completes.

In all honesty, UpdatePanel was Microsoft's first attempt at some sort of Ajax library, and it wasn't exactly their best effort.  Moving away from this wouldn't be the worst idea.  I know that's not the quick answer you were looking for, though.

Comment: but there should be some methods to retain the design elements or to rebind the design elements right ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha - the whole section get's re-rendered.  So if you had some jQuery styling that was happening when the page first loads, then no, that jQuery will not re-fire automatically.  You'll either have to re-fire it manually, or ditch the update panel

Comment: how can i 're-fire' it,I tried giving the link reference and js reference inside update panel,no use.

Comment: @sajanyamaha - I'm afraid I don't know.  I'd ask a new question about that specifically, and be sure to reference whatever jQuery plugin you're using for this dropdown list.